# New layer added to directory doesn't show on GeoServer Layers

Tags: geoserver

I am learning to use GeoServer. I created shp store which is linked to a directory in my computer's C drive. The shps that were originally in the directory appears in Layers fine. But when I added a new shp, it doesn't show in Layers. I've tried restarting GeoServerand (using stop and start GeoServer) and resaving the store, but neither is working.

Comment: Once the store is added to GeoServer it is not re-read by the server. If you need to add layers often consider using single shapefiles or a proper database